# Mutex for a two threaded program one writes the data and other reads it

Tags: c++, mutex

Here is a small sensor class. One thread updates the sensor reading and other read the sensor reading.

```
class Sensor
{
private:
    double data;
    // std::mutex mtx;

public:
    Sensor() : data(0) {}

    void update(double value)
    {   
        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        data = value;
    }

    double get_data() const
    {
        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        return data;
    }
};
```

There are no multiple threads writing only one thread reading and the other writing. So I am not sure, if mutex is need this case ?

Comment: Are you asking whether you need to use a lock if one thread is reading and the other is writing?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, you do need that - or make it `atomic`

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking whether you need to use a lock when thread A is writing and thread B is reading, then the answer is yes because these operations are not atomic.

Answer (score 2):

In this program you can get *torn writes*. Because `data` is a `double` variable, 8 bytes long, a 32-bit processor might write it in two halves, 4 bytes at a time. When reading, it's possible that you read it halfway through a write, so you get a first half and a second half that don't match up.

You can use a mutex to solve this. You can also use an atomic variable, `std::atomic<double>`.